# Basic paintComponent not being called by repaint()?

Tags: java, swing, graphics, paint

I'm using the book *Headfirst java*, and I have put together a program that I thought would compile fine. But when the window is created, the background or oval isn't showing up.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class setup {  
  public static void main(String[] args) {    
    JFrame f = new JFrame();
    System.out.println("Created Frame");
    JPanel myJPan = new JPanel();
    System.out.println("Created Panel");

    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);  
    f.setSize(300,300);
    System.out.println("Set Size");
    f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);  
    f.setContentPane(myJPan);  
    f.setVisible(true);
    System.out.println("Made Visible");
    myJPan.repaint();
  }


  // @Override  ???
  //  "protected void" ??
  public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
      // super.paintComponent(); ???
      g.fillRect(0,0,300,300);
      System.out.println("painted");
      int red = (int) (Math.random()*255);
      int green = (int) (Math.random()*255);
      int blue = (int)(Math.random()*255);
      System.out.println("Got Random Colors");
      Color randomColor = new Color(red, green, blue);
      g.setColor(randomColor);
      System.out.println("Set Random Colors");
      g.fillOval(70,70,100,100);
      System.out.println("Filled Oval");
  }
}
```

Comment: `paintComponent` belongs to the `JPanel` `myJPan` class not the `setup` class

Comment: you're not actually overriding `myJPan`'s `paintComponent` method. You're simply defining a `paintComponent` method in your `setup` class.

Comment: If you had added the `@Override` annotation, the compiler would have told you that you're not actually overriding anything.

Comment: So what is is that I need to do?  I have to override myJPan's paintComponent method?  I don't think I know how to do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16875572/paint-repaint-paintcomponent/16875768#16875768) . It provides an example of the proper way to set up a JPanel.

Like other commenters/answerers have stated, `paintComponent` belongs to the `JPanel` class. What this means for you is that you need to create a class (let's call it `MyPanel`) that **extends** JPanel. (Note: you can either make a new .java file for this class if you are in eclipse or make it an inner class, it should work either way).

Once you have done that, simply cut the paintCOmponent method from your `setup` class and paste it into your new `MyPanel` class.

And finally, within your setup class, instead of creating a `JPanel` object, create a `MyPanel`.

Basically, this `MyPanel` object is your own custom `JPanel` object that does whatever you want it to! It's almost like magic!

On a side note (this will hopefully help you better format your code in the future), and hopefully more experience Java programmers will agree with me on this, I would also recommend that you create your own custom `JFrame` object as well. Only for this one, you won't override any methods other than the `constructor`. Instead, in your `constructor` for this custom `JFrame`, you will make all of the specifications for the window (such as your `setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE` and `setSize(300,300)` calls). This `constructor` is also where you will instantiate your `MyPanel` object (as well as any other component objects in your window) and maybe give it a few `ActionListener`s.

Then, in another class (such as your `setup` class), have a `main` method that has 1 line: one that instantiates a 'JFrame` object. This will automagically create the window.

Oh and one more vitally import thing: you must call `setVisible(true)` on your `JFrame` if you want it to display. I am not sure why it is setup that way.

Comment: Anytime. I also struggled with the concept only a few months ago.

Comment: also, you should mark this as the answer if it truly answers your question

Comment: _recommend that you create your own custom JFrame_ very suboptimal: the general rule (OO 101) is to extend xx only if you enhance its xx-ness. The xx-ness of a JFrame is being top-level container. Mere usage of those services isn't no reason for extension.